# How to load view from application/myfolder/ path in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I was loading view in CodeIgniter as

```
$this->load->view('../../myfolder/footer');
```

It was working fine on windows machine. I have uploaded app to linux machine and start getting error

```
Unable to load the requested file: ../../myfolder/header.php
```

myfolder is in CI application folder.

How can i load view from application/myfolder

Please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like uppercase-lowercase filename problem. On windows it doesn't matter while on unix like systems it does.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need tho load views in application/myfolder?? Code Igniter expects that views are located in application/views or application/views/myfolder. Put your files in application/views and then you can load it using:

```
this->load->view('footer');
```

or

```
this->load->view('myfolder/footer');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it worked on Windows but no longer works on Unix, it could be because the filepaths are case sensitive in Unix.

Check the file structure and file names to make sure they match the CodeIgniter requests exactly.

E.g.:

```
$this->load->view('../../myfolder/footer');
```

Will fail trying to load:

```
../../MyFolder/footer
../../myfolder/Footer
../../MyFolder/Footer
etc
```

Comment: I have checked it very carefully. Case sensitivity isn't issue here.

Comment: Could be that "../.." (if that is what you're typing in) points to a different location on the Unix system.

Comment: All file/folder name are in lower case. May be it is ../../ ... how can  i load view form application/myfolder

Comment: To test, you could try loading the absolute file path, replace the `"../../"` with `"/var/www/application/myfolder/footer"` where `/var/www/` is the path to your web files.

Comment: I tries and got same error Unable to load the requested file: /home/mysite/public_html/myapp/application/commons/header.php

Comment: once I copy the folder in views folder its works. i want to load header/footer  same. How can i load same header footer for every module in CI

Comment: Not sure how to do it in CI, but in other MVC frameworks, you would load the 'main' header/footer in the dispatcher/initial controller so that it would be included on every page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->view(base_url().'myfolder/footer');
```

That should work but I have no idea why you're trying to work outside the views folder to begin with. Just structure your views folder like below. Load the header, footer and anything else that's static from a template page.

Views
--pages
--admin
--templates
--etc.